# How can I access Gmail in another country?

Tags: timezone, gmail, country

I were living in Vietnam, and move to Canada now. I cannot access to my Gmail account
I don't know how to re-verify Gmail account at here and when I turn back Vietnam.
Emergency Help!

Comment: This question is off topic for StackOverflow.  See [What can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).   You might consider asking at [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/F0iLCotAcQI

Hey hope this help you! Let me know :D